# How do I save remote files using visual svn-server?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

The link to the file is like this:

https://somename:8443/!/#distrib/view/head/PostgreSQL/postgresql-9.3.2-1-windows-x64.exe

[image]

[image]

I tried in

- Chrome 'Save link as...' (No action from PC)
- IE9 with 'Save object as...' (Saves strange file always with 1,16K size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking on the 'Raw' button should download the file.

Comment: It works fine! Is there any way to download the whole folder?

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko typically if you wanted to work with SVN you would use a SVN client to do such things.

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko VisualSVN Team is currently working on improving the web interface of VisualSVN Server and introducing new functionality to it. If you have any feedback or a feature request, feel free to contact us at support@visualsvn.com and we will definitely consider it.

Answer (score 2):

Follow-up to @albal's answer:

The button's caption was renamed from "Raw" to "Download" in [VisualSVN Server 3.3.2 patch update](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/#v3.3.2) to avoid such confusion.

> Rename 'Raw' button to 'Download' in web interface.